# Windows page file best practices in regards to dump file?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, swap, pagefile

Last night we had a critical server go down. Running Windows 2012R2. It appears to have been a random blue screen but we can't find much in the logs. We do not seem to have a dump file. Investigating, I found this:

"To take advantage of the dump file feature, your paging file must be on the boot volume. If you have moved the paging file to another volume, you must move it back to the boot volume before you use this feature."
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/system-failure-recovery-options

Our paging file is on it's own drive. I had always thought this was best practice. This server has 320GB RAM. The paging drive is 640GB. The page file is set to "system managed size" on this drive.

[current page settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si5LT.png)

If I also set C: to "system managed size" will that get me a dump file if this happens again? What is the best practice in a scenario like this?

Comment: is it a full dump or a  minidump? What are the settings for this? Minidump is stored in the Windows folder.

Comment: Setting is "automatic memory dump" but we have no dump file. I think because we changed the swap file location.

Comment: You should keep the page file on Drive C: with the operating system. This is best practice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows page file best practices in regards to dump file?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1057139/windows-page-file-best-practices-in-regards-to-dump-file)